# Kronecker limit formula, modular curves, and the class number problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

Let 
$$Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$
be a positive definite quadratic form with $a>0$ and $D=b^2-4ac<0$. Let
$$\zeta_Q(s)=\sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n}Q(m,n)^{-s},$$
the accent indicating that $(0,0)$ is omitted from the sum. According to the [Kronecker limit formula](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wdduke/preprints/kronecker.pdf) we have
$$\lim_{s\to1  +}\left(\lvert D\rvert^{s/2}\zeta_Q(s)-\frac{2\pi }{s-1}\right)=2\pi(2C-\log 4 +H(z_Q))$$
where $C$ is a constant, $z_Q$ is a point in the upper half-plane $\mathfrak H$ such that $Q(z_Q,1)=0,$ and

$$H(z)=-\log(\Im(z)\lvert \eta(z)\rvert^4)$$
$$\eta(z)=q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n),\qquad q = e^{2\pi i z}.$$

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)$ and let
$$L_K(s,\chi)=\sum_{\mathfrak a}\chi(\mathfrak a)N(\mathfrak a)^{-s}\quad\text{and}\quad \zeta(s,\mathcal A)=\sum_{\mathfrak a\in \mathcal A}N(\mathfrak a)^{-s}.$$ 
Here $\chi$ is a character of the class group $\operatorname{Cl}_K$.
We have 
$$L_K(s,\chi)=\sum_\mathcal A\chi(\mathcal A)\zeta(s,\mathcal A).$$
Some work shows that actually $\zeta_Q(s)=\zeta(s,\mathcal A)$ if the class of the quadratic form $Q$ corresponds to the ideal class $\mathcal A$. Multiplying the limit formula by $\chi(\mathcal A)$, summing over the ideal classes, and letting $s\to1+$ therefore gives
$$\frac {1}{2\pi}\lvert D \rvert^{1/2} L_K(1,\chi)=\sum_\mathcal A \chi (\mathcal A) H(z_\mathcal A).\label{f}\tag{1}$$
Here $z_\mathcal A$ is the CM point corresponding to the ideal class $\mathcal A$. Now we specialize $\chi$ to the genus character which is defined as follows in the case when $D$ is a fundamental discriminant, that is, $D$ is the discriminant of $K$. Let $D=D'D''$ be a decomposition of $D$ into fundamental discriminants. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $K$. Then we define
$$ \chi(\mathfrak p)=
\begin{cases}
\chi_{D'}(N(\mathfrak p))\quad \text{if } (D',\mathfrak p)=1\\
\chi_{D''}(N(\mathfrak p))\quad\text{if } (D'',\mathfrak p)=1
\end{cases} $$
Here $\chi_D$ is the Kronecker symbol modulo $\lvert D\rvert$ (the unique real primitive character modulo $\lvert D\rvert$). Each such decomposition corresponds to a decomposition of $L_K(s,\chi)$. Let $L_D(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi_D(n)n^{-s}$. The decomposition is given by
$$L_{D'}(s)L_{D''}(s)=L_K(s,\chi)\label{dec}\tag{2}$$. 
Now the Dirichlet class number formula says that 
$$L_{D}(1)=\begin{cases}\pi \lvert D\rvert^{1/2}h_D\quad \text{if } D<0\\2\lvert D\rvert^{1/2}h_D\log \varepsilon_D \quad \text{if } D>0\end{cases}\label{dir}\tag{3}$$
where $\varepsilon_D$ is the fundamental unit. Combining \eqref{f},\eqref{dec}, and \eqref{dir} we obtain
$$\varepsilon_D^{h_{D'}h_{D''}}=\prod_{\mathcal A}\lvert\Im(z_\mathcal A)^{1/2}\eta(z_\mathcal A)^2\rvert^{-\chi(\mathcal A)}.\label{s}\tag{4}$$

**We proved this formula for fundamental discriminants. How to prove it for arbitrary discriminants?**

The case of non-fundamental discriminants arises in [Siegel's solution](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01425549) of the class number one problem for imaginary quadratic fields.

Suppose that $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field with $h_K=1$. We may write $D_K=-p$, where $p>163$, $p\equiv \pm 2 \text{ ( mod 5)}$ is a prime.

Let $D=-5^2p$ and consider the decomposition $D=TG$, where $T=5,G=-5p$. Since $G$ is divisible by two distinct primes, we have $h_T=2m_p$ for some integer $m_p$. Further we have $h_G=1$, and $ \varepsilon = \varepsilon_g=(1/2)(1+\sqrt 5)$.

Siegel defines two modular functions
$$\phi(z)=-\sqrt 5\frac{\eta\left(\frac {z}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z+1}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z-1}{5}\right)}{\eta\left(5z\right)\eta\left(\frac {z+2}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z-2}{5}\right)}$$ 
$$\psi(z)=-\sqrt 5\frac{\eta\left(\frac {z}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z+2}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z-2}{5}\right)}{\eta\left(5z\right)\eta\left(\frac {z+1}{5}\right)\eta\left(\frac {z-1}{5}\right)}$$

Therefore for a suitable CM point $\tau\in \mathfrak H$ corresponding to the one ideal class of $K$ we have from \eqref{s} 
$$\varepsilon ^{2m_p} =\phi(\tau)$$
if $p\equiv 3 ~(5)$ and $$\varepsilon ^{2m_p} =\psi(\tau)$$ if $p\equiv 2~(5)$.

Next Siegel shows that the functions $\psi$ and $\phi$ are uniformizers for a certain modular curve of genus zero. He obtains relations of the form $j=R_1(\phi)$ and $j=R_2(\psi)$ where $R_1,R_2$ are rational function with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$. We know that the $j$-invariant is a cube of a rational integer at $\tau$. We get therefore equations of the form $\gamma^3=R_i(\varepsilon^{2{m_p}} )$. Siegel is able to solve these, proving thereby that there is no tenth imaginary quadratic field with class number equal to one.

Imin Chen in his [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9632/efb4aee69f8efdb9a016e5d05914018788d8.pdf) interprets Siegel's solution im more modern language. He shows that the Siegel modular functions are in fact uniformizers for the nonsplit Cartan modular curve $X_{ns}^+(5)$.

**Can we always express the uniformizer for $X_{ns}^+(N)$ as an eta-quotient, similarly as Siegel?**
**Which modular curves have uniformizers of this form?**
**What are the canonical references for the Cartan modular curves?**

Comment: What do you mean when you say "uniformizer" for a modular curve? I imagine most mathematicians would interpret a "uniformizer" to be a modular function $f$ so that the function field $K(X)$ is equal to $K(f)$ (where $K$ is some base field, either $\mathbb{Q}$, a number field, or $\mathbb{C}$). This requires the modular curve $X/K$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and in particular to have genus zero (which Siegel's modular curve that is "uniformized" by $\psi$ and $\phi$ is not).

Comment: For any congruence subgroup the generators of the field are polynomial functions of $j,j(\frac{az+ b}{d})$ thus eta quotients. Hence you need to make clear that your two functions generate not only the field of a modular curve but also the coordinate ring of some associated affine curve (defined at first in term of isomorphism classes of elliptic curves with some $N$-th level data) @JeremyRouse so that for each non-singular point there is an uniformizer which is a polynomial in those two functions.

Comment: @JeremyRouse, Thanks, the Siegel's modular curve has genus zero, I have erroneously written one.